# Cant'n login u-boot mode with Udoo neo

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot, beagleboard

I'm new to embedded linux. I read tutorial compile U-boot with Udoo neo board, https://www.udoo.org/docs-neo/Advanced_Topics/Compile_U-Boot_Bootloader.html. I have some questions:

- Compiling u-boot on linux computer. Then I run lsblk on my VMware
  computer, it shows sda partition with sda1 and sda2. The mount
  directories are

> /media/$USER/boot
>
> /media/$USER/udoobuntu

- What is correct path to run 2 commands following above link:

> sudo dd if=SPL of=/dev/*** bs=1K seek=1
>
> sudo dd if=u-boot.img of=/dev/*** bs=1K seek=69

When I ran follow these commands with path /dev/mmcblk0 and insert SD to my Udoo-neo for booting. It showed 3 seconds and press any keys for exit auto reboot. But I don't know what button I need to press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the good old "any key", into the serial console you're using the device on.

Comment: Hello, you mean press any keyboard button?

Comment: Yes, type anything into the terminal application.

Comment: Thank you, the error comes from my keyboard that makes I can't log in u-boot mode

Comment: Then you need to include the full boot log as it's not clear what you mean, thanks.